# Approaching custom foreign keys

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have the following tables

User.

Name
Email
..
password_digest

Company.

Name
Address
...
contact_person_id

So my company have a contact_person, which take a user_id, therefor being a foreign key.

I have tried the following.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one(:user, foreign_key: 'contact_person_id')
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to(:company, :class_name => "Company", :foreign_key => 'contact_person_id')
end
```

But when i try to run my (respond_to) rspecs i get

```
 Failure/Error: before { @company = FactoryGirl.create(:company) }
 ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `contact_person_id'
```

My Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name "Starup Company"
    address "Test street 37"
    zip 2200
    website "http://example.com"
    industry "Construction"
    contact_person user
  end
end
```

What am i doing wrong? And how would i point to user with a company object?

```
company.contact_person
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 issues - you have `belongs_to` and `has_one` reversed and you are calling `contact_person` method on a company, but you defined the relationship to be as a `user`

if you want to use the `contact_person` method on the company, try this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to(:contact_person, class_name: 'User')
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one(:company, :foreign_key => 'contact_person_id')
end
```

This page has a good overview: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one  The foreign key ALWAYS is found in the table with the `belongs_to` association.

The way you wrote it each user can only have one company that they are the contact person for.

To write the rails code the way you have it, you'd have to have the foreign key in the users table.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up Josh, helped me alot. This works, but my specs still fails, am i using the wrong notation with my factory?

Comment: I fixed it using association :contact_person, factory: :user :)